# Can I use OutputCache with file dependency in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

I have a child action method. Can I use `OutputCache` with file dependency?I can see only `SQLDependency` property in `System.Web.Mvc.OutputCacheAttribute`.

Answer (score -2):

*Yes you can use outputcache with file dependency.  Check the following link for more detail.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67z4z916.aspx

OR

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/Asp-Net-mvc-framework-server-side-html-caching-techniques/